# Generating an AWS Signature v4 signature for uploading to s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, cryptography

Okay so I am trying to create an aws v4 signature using [this template from Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) in javascript, with node.js. I am using the template's credentials , region, date, and service in order to test my signing function.

I am using the following format to generate my signature:
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MjuG.png)

My StringToSign is the base64 encoded POST policy from the template :

```
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
```

And my signing key is generated using the following code from acquired from the amazon signature v4 key derivation template

```
var crypto = require("crypto-js");

function getSignatureKey(Crypto, key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
var kDate = Crypto.HmacSHA256(dateStamp, "AWS4" + key);
var kRegion = Crypto.HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
var kService = Crypto.HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
var kSigning = Crypto.HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
return kSigning;
}
```

My key is the SecretAccessKey from the template linked above
    (wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY)
, my date is "20151229", my region is "us-east-1" and my service name is "s3"

And finally, to get the output I am using

```
var signature = cryptojs.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, signingKey).toString()
```

The expected output from the calculation is:

```
46503978d3596de22955b4b18d6dfb1d54e8c5958727d5bdcd02cc1119c60fc9
```

But the output I am getting is:

```
8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e
```

If you see where I went wrong please let me know as I think I have followed amazon's template but it seems I have made an error somewhere

Comment: why don't just use something like https://github.com/mhart/aws4 ?

Comment: Or the AWS JavaScript SDK, of course, but I presume there's a good reason. Perhaps it's academic interest (which I encourage and promote).

Comment: I entered in real data instead of test data and the upload just worked. I still don't know if I was reading something wrong, but I changed nothing in the code and the upload authenticates just fine.

Comment: I'm starting to believe that the `46503978d3596de22955b4b18d6dfb1d54e8c5958727d5bdcd02cc1119c60fc9` in their docs is simply wrong and the correct is what you got `8afdbf4008c03f22c2cd3cdb72e4afbb1f6a588f3255ac628749a66d7f09699e`, which is what I'm getting also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Signature Version 4 S3 Upload using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974128/aws-signature-version-4-s3-upload-using-node-js)