# Android AWS S3 Signature V4 Post using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, amazon-s3, httpurlconnection

I am trying to do a direct post to Amazon S3 on Android using the new Signature V4, not with their SDK, using `HttpURLConnection` (I recently upgraded from `HttpClient`). I have the `HttpURLConnection` portion working with the previous signature version (even with multi-part entities), so I don't think that is the problem but I mention it in case it is.

The code looks like this:

```
String charset = "UTF-8";
MultiPartUtility multipart = new MultiPartUtility(url, charset);
multipart.addFormField("Content-Type", contentType);
multipart.addFormField("Policy", policy);
multipart.addFormField("key", key);
multipart.addFormField("acl", acl);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String date = formatter.format(new Date());
String credential = accessKey + "/" + date + "/" + region + "/s3/aws4_request";
multipart.addFormField("X-Amz-Signature", signature);
multipart.addFormField("X-Amz-Credential", credential);
multipart.addFormField("X-Amz-Date", date + "T000000Z"); // 
multipart.addFormField("x-amz-meta-uuid", uuid");
multipart.addFormField("x-amz-server-side-encryption","AES256");
multipart.addFormField("X-Amz-Algorithm","AWS4-HMAC-SHA256");
multipart.addFormField("x-amz-meta-tag","");

multipart.addFilePart("file", file);
String response = multipart.finish();
```

The `MultiPartUtility` class is just handling all the craziness associated with the new `HttpURLConnection` issues with mult-part entity posts (which I think is still needed in this circumstance). The code for that can be found here, with a couple slight fixes I had to make:

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically

This results in an End of File exception, so I suspect I have something wrong in these values or am formatting them incorrectly.

From the Amazon examples I have found posting from a web page it looks like they are encrypting the values:

[Generating an AWS Signature v4 signature for uploading to s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109865/generating-an-aws-signature-v4-signature-for-uploading-to-s3)

In non HTTP example is almost looks like they are pushing the value into a different object.

Had anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I was missing the Content-Type value - was blank, and was then causing an end of file exception. Rather surprising that exception was so vague. Oh well.