# AWS Signature Version 4 S3 Upload using Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hmac

I've been following the AWS example on how to generate a V4 HMAC signature. I've done this successfully in Java but I'm trying to get it to work in Node/JavaScript. When I use my code I generate all the correct intermediary keys in their 1st example below but on the next example when given the test StringToSign the same code that generated the correct intermediary keys fails to generate the supposed correct signature.

**Correct Intermediary Keys:**

```
secretkey = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
dateStamp = '20120215'
regionName = 'us-east-1'
serviceName = 'iam'

kSecret  = '41575334774a616c725855746e46454d492f4b374d44454e472b62507852666943594558414d504c454b4559'
kDate    = '969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d'
kRegion  = '69daa0209cd9c5ff5c8ced464a696fd4252e981430b10e3d3fd8e2f197d7a70c'
kService = 'f72cfd46f26bc4643f06a11eabb6c0ba18780c19a8da0c31ace671265e3c87fa'
kSigning = 'f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a000a1a9e090d414db404d'
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html.

**Fails With the Following Input**

```
secretkey = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
dateStamp = '20151229'
regionName = 'us-east-1'
serviceName = 's3'
```

**StringToSign**
  eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDE1LTEyLTMwVDEyOjAwOjAwLjAwMFoiLA0KICAiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6IFsNCiAgICB7ImJ1Y2tldCI6ICJzaWd2NGV4YW1wbGVidWNrZXQifSwNCiAgICBbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwgIiRrZXkiLCAidXNlci91c2VyMS8iXSwNCiAgICB7ImFjbCI6ICJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9LA0KICAgIHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fcmVkaXJlY3QiOiAiaHR0cDovL3NpZ3Y0ZXhhbXBsZWJ1Y2tldC5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL3N1Y2Nlc3NmdWxfdXBsb2FkLmh0bWwifSwNCiAgICBbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwgIiRDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiLCAiaW1hZ2UvIl0sDQogICAgeyJ4LWFtei1tZXRhLXV1aWQiOiAiMTQzNjUxMjM2NTEyNzQifSwNCiAgICB7IngtYW16LXNlcnZlci1zaWRlLWVuY3J5cHRpb24iOiAiQUVTMjU2In0sDQogICAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIkeC1hbXotbWV0YS10YWciLCAiIl0sDQoNCiAgICB7IngtYW16LWNyZWRlbnRpYWwiOiAiQUtJQUlPU0ZPRE5ON0VYQU1QTEUvMjAxNTEyMjkvdXMtZWFzdC0xL3MzL2F3czRfcmVxdWVzdCJ9LA0KICAgIHsieC1hbXotYWxnb3JpdGhtIjogIkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifSwNCiAgICB7IngtYW16LWRhdGUiOiAiMjAxNTEyMjlUMDAwMDAwWiIgfQ0KICBdDQp9

**Correct Signature:** 46503978d3596de22955b4b18d6dfb1d54e8c5958727d5bdcd02cc1119c60fc9
**My Signature:** e7318f0bfd7d86fb9ba81c314f62192ee2baf7273792ef01ffafeb430fc2fb68

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

**My Code**

```
var crypto = require("crypto-js")

module.exports.getSignatureKey = function(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
    var kSecret = "AWS4" + key
    var kDate = crypto.HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret)
    var kRegion = crypto.HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate)
    var kService = crypto.HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion)
    var kSigning = crypto.HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService)
    return kSigning;
}

module.exports.sign = function(signatureKey,stringToSign) {
    var unencodedSignature = crypto.HmacSHA256(stringToSign,signatureKey)
    return unencodedSignature
}

module.exports.getSignature = function(stringToSign,secretKey,dateStamp,regionName, serviceName) {
    var signingKey = this.getSignatureKey(secretKey,dateStamp,regionName,serviceName)

    return this.sign(signingKey,stringToSign)
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to write the signing code yourself but just wanted to mention that there are, of course, other options including the NPM aws4 module, as well as the AWS JavaScript SDK.

Comment: @jarmod Partly, but when I was pulling my hair out I threw in the towel and tried two node modules specifically for s3 upload. I was unsuccessful using both. To be honest given that you can do this in 3 functions I have no idea why the existing Npm modules are so verbose.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil ,  i am looking for this kind of solution. Can you share the link of tutorial/ steps that you followed to generate the signature and authorization headers. Thanks in advance

Comment: @sravanthi In the first link in my question there are examples of how to build the needed functions. If you look at the parent links in that directory the higher level concept of what you are trying to do is explained. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS example in the second link has the wrong signature. Using my solution I am able to successfully upload to s3.

Something else to consider is that the crypto-js node library outputs the signatures already in hex. Theres no need to do a manual conversion yourself as you would if you we in Java using the example code they provide.

Comment: How did you generate the String to Sign from Code ?

Comment: @RadheshKhanna Its the base 64 encoded data that I want to sign. In this case form data described here -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Comment: @RadheshKhanna See my link in my above comment. It provides an example of JSON data converted to base64 to create a string to sign. I believe I used one of the Java base64 encoding libraries.